# Multiple models with similar fields Django

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have 2 models:

```
User
Customer
```

They both have the following SHARED fields:

```
First name
Last name
Pin code
Id
```

They also have a shared save() method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            id = secrets.token_urlsafe(8)
            while User.objects.filter(id=id).count() != 0:
                id = secrets.token_urlsafe(8)
            self.id = id
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**How could I create a Base model that they can extend so that I don't need to define all of these things twice? Thanks!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an [*abstract* base class [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) that implements the common logic, and then inherit:

```
class MyBaseClass(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        model = self._meta.model
        if not self.pk:
            id = secrets.token_urlsafe(8)
            while model.objects.filter(id=id).exists():
                id = secrets.token_urlsafe(8)
            self.id = id
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class User(MyBaseClass):
    pass

class Customer(MyBaseClass):
    pass
```

An abstract class will thus not construct a table, it basically is used to inherit fields, methods, etc. to avoid rewriting the same logic twice.

Comment: So this is the same logic that applies when extending the standard `User` model, right? You should extend from the `BaseUser` (I don't remember if it was called exactly like that) instead of `User` directly.

Comment: @revliscano: exactly, an `AbstractUserModel` is an abstract base class as well: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L60

Comment: Thanks!! Quick question: in the save model, you wrote super(User, self)... did you mean to write super(model, self)??

Comment: Actually - it didn't work!! Sorry for the confusion. When I try to create a new User I get a maximum recursion depth exceeded error. Do you know why?

Comment: @NGI: that typically means you have a function that keeps calling itself.

Comment: Yes, it is the save method that keeps calling itself over and over, however, this only happens when I use model=self._meta.model.

Comment: @NGI: can you edit the question show the traceback as well as the model you work with?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help! Just to confirm, you want the error message I am getting for the recursion and the model I am extending MyBaseClass with?

Comment: @NGI: did you replace `super(User, self)` with `super()`? If not, that will resolve to the same method. Since the super method of user is the `MyBaseClass.save`.

Comment: I did that and no longer receive the recursion error!!! However, I know get this: `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` how do I solve this?

Comment: @NGI: it will, since `model` will be replaced by `User`/`Customer`, so it walks up the MRO, and the first hit will be the `save` method of the `MyBaseClass`, you thus should not use `super(model, self)`, but just `super()`. This will walk up the MRO from the point where you *defined* the method.

Comment: @NGI: it means that you likely have a `ForeignKey` somewhere that contains a value that is not a primary key of the "target" value.

Comment: What is MRO? Also, what does it mean to be a primary key of the target value? Thank you so much for all your help!! Sorry, new to this stuff. If you couldnt tell ;)

Comment: @NGI: http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/python/mro.aspx#:~:text=Method%20Resolution%20Order%20(MRO)%20is,lets%20examine%20a%20few%20cases.

Comment: @NGI: A `ForeignKey` refers to an object, and it stores its primary key to do so. So it stores `2` if it wants to point to a model object with `id=2`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I literally recognize your name from all the django posts ive seen answered here! Thank you!!!

Comment: Figured it out btw